# Php: mysql_ping showing error [PDO]

Tags: php, pdo

I am working on a code written by my ex-colleague and when running it I am getting a warning saying that mysql_ping has been deprecated. This is causing the execution to slow down considerably. The culprit is the below line of code in the php class which is extending the PDO class. I am trying to understand why the mysql_ping was used in first place. The comments indicate that this is to close old connections but I am wondering what old connection?

```
private function closeMySQLConnection() {
     /**
     * This function is needed to close the old library connection.
     * In the migration process server will connect dual ways.
     * 1) MySQL library
     * 2) PDO library
     * So this one will close the older one connection.
     */
    try {
        if (mysql_ping())
            mysql_close();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What should I do so that the warning is not displayed and I can ensure the below functionality is still maintained. Should I just use:

```
$this->pdo = null;
```

Comment: use mysqli_ping(); I don't quite understand what u mean with has to be closed ..

Comment: Stop using the deprecated [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) extension and consider using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) may be?

Comment: is closeMySQLConnection needed as part of PDO construct?